# Matlab solve system of symbolic trigonometric equations

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve a system of 12 equations with complex trigonometric terms, preferably with symbolic variables. I found a few questions already, but none of the answers seem to apply to what I'm doing.
an example of the equations:

```
 sin(t5)*sin(tA) - cos(t5)*cos(tA)*sin(tB) == q11
cos(t5)*sin(tA) + cos(tA)*sin(t5)*sin(tB) == q12
cos(tA)*cos(tB) == q13
 95*cos(t1) + 95*cos(tA) + 35*sin(tA) + 60*cos(t3)*cos(tA) + 110*cos(tA)*cos(tB) == q14
- cos(tA)*sin(t5) - cos(t5)*sin(tA)*sin(tB) == q21
sin(t5)*sin(tA)*sin(tB) - cos(t5)*cos(tA) == q22
cos(tB)*sin(tA) == q23
 95*sin(t1) - 35*cos(tA) + 95*sin(tA) + 60*cos(t3)*sin(tA) + 110*cos(tB)*sin(tA) == q24
cos(t5)*cos(tB) == q31
-cos(tB)*sin(t5) == q32
sin(tB) == q33
60*sin(t3) + 110*sin(tB) + 175 == q34
```

My code:

```
syms t1 t2 t3 t4 t5;
m = model(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5);
syms tA tB;
%replace the 90 with pi/2 cause the cos that accepts syms is in radians
m=subs(m, 90,pi/2);
m=simplify(m);
%t1+t2 = tA and t3+t4=tB
m = subs(m, [t1+t2 t3+t4],[tA tB]);
m=simplify(m);
%solving?
syms q11 q12 q13 q14 q21 q22 q23 q24 q31 q32 q33 q34;
wanted=[q11 q12 q13 q14 q21 q22 q23 q24 q31 q32 q33 q34];
equations=sym(zeros(3*4,1));
for i=1:3
    for j=1:4
        equations((i-1)*4+j)=m(i,j)==wanted((i-1)*4+j);
       % fprintf('q%d%d = %s\n',i,j,char(m(i,j)));
    end
end

res = solve(equations,[t1 t3 t5 tA tB])
```

note that in this, model(5 angles) returns a 4x4 matrix (basically the sin/cos terms), from which I extract the equations, which I then simplify a bit. The goal here is to have a set of equations to obtain the 5 angles from the known qij.
The problem here is that solve() always indicates that there are no solutions, even when given numerical parameters for the qij (and it is known that the system should have a solution with these parameters).